# Building a board layout by including 8 times another layout : unique cells identifiers?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to design a chess board, but by including 8 times another layout containing 8 ImageView. Then, how can I have unique android:id for all 64 squares components ?

I would like the included layout to be designed as this :

LinearLayout (orientation : horizontal)
 -> ImageView
 -> ...
 -> ImageView

Another point, is having LinearLayout for the parent and the included layout the best performance technique ? I thought of using RelativeLayout, but I don't see how I can manage.

Comment: For a chess board, I would probably use a TableLayout. Also each ImageView in the "board" layout should have it's own android:id attribute which will assign each one a unique identifier.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks. I forgot the TableLayout, because I went from a API 3 phone to a API 15 one (and TableLayout was not available for API 3). And furthermore, the technical articles on official website said that layouts reusing is a good technique. But I agree that in this case : I win nothing with layout reusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a TableLayout as Code Guru mentioned here is sample code that will help you to create the chess board you are looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />
    </TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1 />

  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/block16"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2 />
    </TableRow>
```

And so on and so forth...you could if you wanted to use a white and black background color alternatively instead of an image.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I do need ImageLayout, because I plan to import chess pieces images inside.

Comment: Since this layout is quite regular (and long), you might want to create it in Java code where you can take advantage of for loops.

Comment: You're right, but in my case I should use xml : as I am designing for the 4 sizes small, normal, large and xlarge. Xml is better for handling several screen configurations.